# Add word to permalink when custom field has a value

Tags: url-rewriting

I would like to change the default permalink structure of posts (and all other types) that have a specfic post meta value.

So when it doesn't have that value it just stays:
http://website.com/page-title

But when it does changes to:
http://website.com/page-title/plus/

So 'plus' is added because meta key 'plus' has the value of 1.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Interesting question.  I guess hooking into the save process and updating it then would probably be first thing I tried.  Why do you want this behaviour?

Comment: To recognize a 'plus' post/page/(any other post type) for users but also in analytics. There is now no way I can filter on plus pages.

Comment: What sort of filters do you want? Google analytics lets you pass custom variables directly to it and you can make custom queries in wordpress.  Not sure what filters you mean.

Comment: To see how many 'plus' articles have been read, how long they have been read, bounce rate, etc.
Since this are articles that you can't read when you are not logged in, it would be handy to get specific statistics on not logged in views and logged in views.

Comment: I don't think changing the URL makes sense here, just alter the output of google analytics to flag these pages.  What method are you using to add the analytics javascript?

Comment: I'm using Universal Analytics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23335/discussion-between-jeffrey-van-rossum-and-guerrilla).